# Xamarin HttpClient request

Tags: android, xamarin, androidhttpclient

Hi Xamarin Jedi masters !!!

I need a litle help First, I set the value of the Token

```
user.Token = "email@hotmail.com:1395694497451:799fcaa9f86ff10604ca0c6135313697";
```

Then I added the property to the Header :)

```
request.Headers.Add ("Auth-Token", user.Token); <------ HERE !!!
```

Then I call: `var response = client.SendAsync (request).Result;`

I´m receiving the message :

> Unauthorized: Authentication token was either missing or invalid.
>
> description This request requires HTTP authentication

BUT .. LISTEN !!!

If I put directly.... that way: `request.Headers.Add ("Auth-Token", "email@hotmail.com:1395694497451:799fcaa9f86ff10604ca0c6135313697");`

works !!!!!!!

Please ..... Somebody tell me how I can fix that and use the value that came from property user.Token......

sorry about my english

Comment: Hello Ozory, welcome to Stackoverflow. The code should be same, if modifying the `user` object does not have any side-effects. Is it used for anything else in that request, e.g. request signing?

Comment: Guys, you will not believe!

It was simply remove quotes

@ user.Token.Trim ('"') <---- MAGIC!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will not believe!

It was simply remove quotes

@ user.Token.Trim ('"') <---- MAGIC!

Comment: Believe it or not, it worked for me to do this in a similar issue I just had. I do understand it may not work for all situations but it will for some - Thank you! Xamarin is full of nasty bugs! :)